# how to use rosbag API?

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I collected odometry data from dspace. It's a .csv file. I want to write it into a rosbag file to do Gmapping. I searched other similar questions and the answers are rosbag API.

So I'm following the [API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API). I want to first try a simple example by writing some simple messages into rosbag. After I write down the code as .cpp file, What should I do next? Do I need to specially create a package for this? (Now it reports rosbag/bag.h no such file or directory)

```
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
int main(argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"bagit");
    rosbag::Bag bag;
    bag.open('test.bag',rosbag::bagmode::Write);

    std_msgs::String str;
    str.data=std::string("foo");

    std_msgs::Int32 i;
    i.data=42;
    bag.write("chatter",ros::Time::now(),str);
    bag.write("number",ros::Time::now(),i);

    bag.close();
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256428/how-to-use-rosbag-api?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-03-08**:
This is not a question, the link you provide is not a tutorial. Describe what you want to do, what your problem is, what you expect to happen and what actually happens. Otherwise, we cannot help you!

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-08**:
@mig Thanks for reminding. I have revised my question. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am assuming you have already created a workspace with a package that has a CMakeList.txt file and package.xml file with std_msgs specified where necessary.

To answer your question:

1. bag.open() takes a string of type std::string const &filename as its first parameter, so change from using ' ' to using " " when specifying a file name.
2. As this is just an exercise, I would put the hard path to file so you know exactly where the bag file will be saved.
3. 'catkin build <package_name>' the package that you created.
4. Create a launch file with the node that has the type as the executable that you just created and place in launch directory (you will have to create this directory).
5. Launch the launch file, by using roslaunch.

EDIT:
For step 3., use `catkin_make --pkg <package_name>` as per @chwimmer point in the comments.

---

Originally posted by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) with karma: 265 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) on 2017-05-22**:
Goog answer. Just be carefull with point 3: Many beginners dont use catkin tools and dont know that this exists. This step would fail than. Just catkin_make --pkg <package_name> would be better. Every catkin tools user would know than too what to do.